# How to print data for one MySqL record in Angular

Tags: html, mysql, angular, spring-boot

I have a table `flight` in my MySqL database:

[image]

I want to show in my Spring Boot application data only for the first record with `flight_id=1`

Here is my json

[image]

myflights-list.component.html:

```
<h3>Ticket</h3>

<div *ngIf="flight">
<div>
<label>departureCity: </label> {{flight.departureCity}}
</div>
<div>
<label>destinationCity: </label> {{flight.destinationCity}}
</div>
<div>
<label>price: </label> {{flight.price}}
</div>
<div>
<label>flightDuration: </label> {{flight.flightDuration}}
</div>
<div>
<label>transferNumber: </label> {{flight.transferNumber}}
</div>
<div>
<label>departureDate: </label> {{flight.departureDate}}
</div>
<div>
<label>departureTime: </label> {{flight.departureTime}}
</div>

<hr/>
</div>
```

myflights-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
 selector: 'myflights-list',
 templateUrl: './myflights-list.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./myflights-list.component.css']
})
export class MyflightsListComponent implements OnInit {

flight: Flight = new Flight();
flights: Observable<Flight>;
flight_id: number;
constructor(private flightService: FlightService,
          private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private token: TokenStorageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  ngOnInit() {
 /*  this.flight_id = 1;*/
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.flight_id = params['flight_id']; });
 this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id).subscribe(t => this.flight = t);
 this.flight_id = this.flight.flight_id;
 this.reloadData();
}
this.reloadData();
}

reloadData() {
this.flights = this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id);
}}
```

flight.ts

```
export class Flight {
flight_id: number;
departureCity: string;
destinationCity: string;
price: number;
flightDuration: number;
transferNumber: number;
departureDate: Date;
departureTime: Time;
tickets: Ticket[];
}
export class Ticket {
ticket_id: number;
place: number;
user_id: number;
flight_id: number;
}
```

flight.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Flight} from './flight';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlightService {

private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/flights';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getFlight(flight_id: number): Observable<Flight> {
return this.http.get<Flight>(`${this.baseUrl}/${flight_id}`);
}
```

In my Spring Boot it looks like on the picture. Unfortunately, no data for my flight with `flight_id=1`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two ways:

Whether You have to subscribe to your service directly to get your data :

```
 this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id).subscribe((response) => {

      this.flight = response;

    });
  }
```

---

Or, as you'd intended to do using your `flights` Observable, subscribe also :

```
reloadData() {

  this.flights = this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id);

  this.flights.subscribe((response) => {

     this.flight = response;

    });
  }}
}}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you also help me to get `flight_id` from the address path, not like I write `this.flight_id = 1;`

Comment: @Viola yes, Welcome, are u using angular routing, or not implemented yet ?

Comment: look please on my `myflights-list.component.ts` class, I've tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Viola, not enough, where is your routing configuration ?

Comment: I don't know what I should add

Comment: @Viola, did you add a similar thing [to this](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration) in your code ?

Comment: yes, I have configuration, because in other class routing works, but in this class doesn't

Comment: @Viola, could you add your relevant routing part, and it would be better to create a simple stackblitz.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914927/how-to-get-data-from-adress-path-in-angular

Comment: maybe you know answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907585/how-to-show-foreign-key-in-angular-using-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Need to susbscribe to the `getFlight` method.

```
reloadData() {
 this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id).subscribe((data) => {

   this.flights = data
  });
}}
```