# How to get id from adress path in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I want to print data for the record with `flight_id=1` from my table `flight`, but get this id from the adress path, like on the picture:

[image]

It works, but only if I write smth like this `this.flight_id = 1;`, but I want to get the `flight_id` from the address here: `localhost:4200/myflight/1`

Here is my table `flight`:

[image]

I've added all required configuration in `app.module.ts`

My class `myflights-list.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { FlightService } from '../flight.service';
import { Flight } from '../flight';
import {TicketService} from '../ticket.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Ticket} from '../auth/jwt-response';

@Component({
selector: 'myflights-list',
templateUrl: './myflights-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./myflights-list.component.css']
})
export class MyflightsListComponent implements OnInit {

flight: Flight = new Flight();
flights: Observable<Flight>;
flight_id: number;
constructor(private ticketService: TicketService, private flightService: FlightService,
          private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
/*  this.flight_id = 1;*/
this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.flight_id = params['flight_id']; });
this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id).subscribe(t => this.flight = t);
this.reloadData();
}

reloadData() {
this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id).
subscribe((response) => {
  this.flight = response;
});
}
}
```

flight.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Flight} from './flight';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlightService {

private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/flights';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getFlight(flight_id: number): Observable<Flight> {
return this.http.get<Flight>(`${this.baseUrl}/${flight_id}`);
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyflightsListComponent } from './myflights-list/myflights-list.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {httpInterceptorProviders} from './auth/auth-interceptor';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  MyflightsListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [httpInterceptorProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MyflightsListComponent } from './myflights-list/myflights-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'myflight/:flight_id', component: MyflightsListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Add your routing file / part to the question please

Comment: Hi, Your question is not quite clear. Your code and the output you want aren't matching. Please be more clear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry, I edit my question

Comment: All you need to do is put `this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id)` inside your `route` subscription: `this.route.params.subscribe(params => { });` due to observable stream.

Comment: @penleychan unfortunately, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.flight_id = params['flight_id']; });
  this.reloadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `route.snapshot` is a static image of the route information shortly after the component was created.

You can subscribe to `paramMap` from `activatedRoute` snapshot and get the param value:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.flight_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('ticket_id');
}
```

Comment: why ticket_id? I've got error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: because you `flight_id` is defined as a number in your component which will be a string from route params. Route parameters are always strings. and `ticket_id` because your router uses `ticket_id` in configuration for the flight route

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){ }

ngOnInit(){
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.flight_id = params['flight_id'];
  });
}
```